# android rectF warning

Tags: android, draw, rect

I draw an oval on a canvas:

```
RectF f = new RectF(-r, -r, r, r);
canvas.drawOval(f , mPaint);
```

Why I see warning on RectF?

> Avoid object allocations during draw/layout operations (preallocate
>   and reuse instead)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's just what it says: doing a `new RectF` inside `onDraw` creates an object every time anything is drawn. This can be a lot of objects. Just use a single `RectF`:

```
RectF mRect = new RectF();

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    mRect.set(-r, -r, r, r);
    canvas.drawOval(mRect, mPaint);
}
```

Just to be clear: your original code is logically correct. This is just a performance improvement (albeit an important one).

Answer (score 2):

Just create the RectF object once and reuse it every time you draw otherwise you will create too many RectF objects which may affect the performances.